# Linearize nonlinear constraints for optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to linearize the following constraint:

$x*y*z + a*b + s*t = 1$,

where all variables are binary.

I read that this is possible using the "big-M" method, but was not sure how to apply it when there are multiple terms, or perhaps, there is another method?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the variables?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo x,y,z,a,b,s,t.

Comment: The usual convention is to pick the first letters of the alphabet to denote that which is known and the last to denote that which is unknown.

Comment: I would delete this question and re-post it at http://or.stackexchange.com where there are plenty of questions of that form. Integer programming is not very popular at Math SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the desired logical proposition
$$[(x \land y \land z) \land \neg (a \land b) \land \neg(s \land t)]
\lor
[\neg (x \land y \land z) \land (a \land b) \land \neg(s \land t)]
\lor
[\neg (x \land y \land z) \land \neg (a \land b) \land (s \land t)]
$$
in conjunctive normal form yields
$$(\neg a\lor \neg b\lor \neg s\lor \neg t)\land (\neg a\lor \neg b\lor \neg x\lor \neg y\lor \neg z)\land (a\lor s\lor x)\land (a\lor s\lor y)\land (a\lor s\lor z)\land (a\lor t\lor x)\land (a\lor t\lor y)\land (a\lor t\lor z)\land (b\lor s\lor x)\land (b\lor s\lor y)\land (b\lor s\lor z)\land (b\lor t\lor x)\land (b\lor t\lor y)\land (b\lor t\lor z)\land (\neg s\lor \neg t\lor \neg x\lor \neg y\lor \neg z),$$
which corresponds to linear constraints
\begin{align}
1- a+ 1- b+ 1- s+ 1- t&\ge 1\\
1- a+ 1- b+ 1- x+ 1- y+ 1- z&\ge 1\\
a+ s+ x&\ge 1\\
a+ s+ y&\ge 1\\
a+ s+ z&\ge 1\\
a+ t+ x&\ge 1\\
a+ t+ y&\ge 1\\
a+ t+ z&\ge 1\\
b+ s+ x&\ge 1\\
b+ s+ y&\ge 1\\
b+ s+ z&\ge 1\\
b+ t+ x&\ge 1\\
b+ t+ y&\ge 1\\
b+ t+ z&\ge 1\\
1- s+ 1- t+ 1- x+ 1- y+ 1- z&\ge 1
\end{align}

An alternative approach introduces a new variable for each product and then linearizes the products:
\begin{align}
u+v+w &= 1\\
u &\le x\\
u &\le y\\
u &\le z\\
u &\ge x + y + z - 2 \\
v &\le a\\
v &\le b\\
v &\ge a + b - 1 \\
w &\le s\\
w &\le t\\
w &\ge s + t - 1 \\
u,v,w &\ge 0
\end{align}